# не выводятся таблицы в Sqlite3 не работает команда .tables

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite3, table

У меня windows 8, когда я создал в таблицу командой `.open table.db` и после этого вожу в командной стройке `.tables` таблицы не отображаются в командной строке.

Comment: командой `.open` вы создали базу данных, а не таблицу. В только что созданной базе никаких таблиц нет, пока вы не создадите их с помощью create table. А раз таблиц нет, то и .tables показывать нечего

Comment: create table tb1(a, z) он мне выдал ошибку

Comment: даже точку в начеле поставил

Comment: все разобрался спасибо